# Create a C++ program to find the number of pairs of integers in a given array of integers whose sum is equal to a specified number

Tags: c++

Write a C++ program to find the number of pairs of integers in a given array of integers whose sum is equal to a specified number. The program will ask the user to input 10 numbers and check if a pair of integers will be equal to a user-specified number.

Your program will show the location of the pair of integers in the array and their corresponding values.

SAMPLE INPUT:

```
Enter an array of integers: 75 90 100 32 1 55 92 123 56 10
Sum of pairs of integers: 101
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
The location of the pair of integers are number[2] and number[4] and the values are 
100 and 1, respectively
```

Comment: please read [ask] and rewrite your quistion

Comment: sort the vector and let two iterators walk the vector in opposite direction, did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you'd like to implement it, you could consider a recursive approach similar to this:

```
void pairAddToK(vector<int> L, int left, int right, int K) {
    if (left == right) // Our base case
       return;
    if (left + 1 == right) { // 2 elements, check if they add to K
       if (L[left] + L[right] == K)
          cout << L[left] << " + " << L[right] << " = " << K << endl;
    }

    int mid = (left + right) / 2; // General case, use recursion to divide and conquer
    
    pairAddToK(L, left, mid, K);
    pairAddToK(L, mid + 1, right, K);

    for (int i = left; i <= mid; i++) // Check for pairs from both halves
       for (int j = mid + 1; j <= right; j++)
           if (L[i] + L[j] == K)
              cout << L[i] " + " << L[j] << " = " << K << endl;
}
```

Something along these lines should work. I did not test this and wrote this only inside the StackOverflow answer box, so let me know if this needs clarity.

Answer (score -1):

You will need a nested while loop or nested for-loop.

check if arr[0] + arr[1] == sum_of_pair_of_int
if it is, insert it into the pair... an array can work too.
then check if arr[0] + arr[2].
repeat for rest of array.
then start at arr[1] + arr[2], then arr[1] + arr[3], etc.

If you have a more specific question, that would be more helpful.